# Output multiple WMIC commands to the same file

Tags: c#, javascript, windows, visual-studio-2010, wmic

I was wondering if there is a way to output multiple WMIC commands to the same file. I want to run these commands below but want to output the results in the same file.

```
wmic /node:"pcname" /USER:"username" /PASSWORD:"pwd"/output:c:\file1.htm  csproduct list full/format:hform.xsl


wmic /node:"pcname" /USER:"username" /PASSWORD:"pwd"/output:c:\file1.htm  bios list full/format:hform.xsl
```

I would like to have the info outputed in the same file, one after the other.

Comment: I found my answer, the command was /append. Now is it possible to run both of these in the same command? Or do i have to run both commands one after the other?

Comment: WMIC doesn't support multiple queries so you have to run separate WMIC command calls for 1 output. Also if /APPEND doesn't work for you, can always use DOS redirection '>>' to append.